# Strange messages in my syslog on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, syslog, linux-kernel, lxc

I am getting strange messages on my /var/log/syslog that aren't usual.

I am running a Debian Jessie LXC Container inside of a Debian Wheezy machine. But I believe this is not the problem.

An example of them:

> Dec 10 16:30:59 gtbono kernel: 18Id  rn032 d:xwe24.]afi l1: tr g1<4049Irfrxtr g1>08Idfftng0470vr x  h<14] orwre1>08Idfftng03.]afi l1[7]dwnh>7]d wnh>7]d wnham2acus<17] orwre1>28Idfftng0488  cp wl 790aneion2[80Pd:ihgt
>
> Dec 10 16:30:59 gtbono kernel: 3.56cp wl 790 aneion2[80Pd:ihgt
>
> Dec 10 16:54:55 gtbono kernel: 3.46cp wl 703 aneion2[31Pd:ihgt<04Prrt140Irrt 140Irrt 140Irrt 140Irrt 1rg

They pop out very often and aren't following an specific schedule.

I am wondering what the heck is this? Some hardware fault or maybe some form of attack?

Comment: looks more like a bug ?

Comment: very strange, never saw this before, I've installed the server from a debootstrap just like I always do, and even if I reinstall, it continues :(